# Any follow-up to videoHD Stitching Project by Luke Yeager?

Tags: html5-video, surround

any progress made in stitching video since the last answer by Luke Yeager ?

I plan to develop 360 surround view for my car
Since --- StitcHD Project --- by Luke is already 5 years old
I expect some progress to be announced in technology, faster GPU live video processing and better depth maps matching.

https://github.com/lukeyeager/StitcHD

I would prefer WebRTC video tools but didn't get any answer on how to connect 4 usb webcams and get 4 live video streams for stitching.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enumerate all devices using WebRTC, 
    https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/

shows how to do that and then open a specific device. You can open multiple devices at the same time but mind you that this is going to be taxing for the USB bus.

The [canvas sample](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/canvas/) which shows how to grab a frame from the video stream and convert it into an image might be useful too.

Comment: Thank you Philipp for your kind reply. "+1" goes to you.  I have already tested the above samples and tens of others.  To stitch 2 live video streams I need to get  2 instances of getUserMedia() to work in parallel. None sample to offer such functionality yet. Basing on HTML5 video manual, what is offered is exactly an option to toggle between a number of usb webcams via getUserMedia()  supported by Chrome, not supported by Firefox (for me).  You said "You can open multiple devices at the same time". Do you mean 2 usb webcam video streams processed in parallel ?   Any working sample ? thanks

Comment: you combine enumerateDevices with calling getUserMedia with a deviceId as shown in the input-output sample

Comment: Thank you Philipp.  I have contacted you via Twitter since SOF offers no P2P functionality.  I fully understand what you say but I am stuck with a single usb webcam service only. If I open 2 instances of Firefox or Chrome (Snap a Photo demo) so the first webcam selected locks second instance of FF or Chrome making 2nd webcam selection to fail.  Maybe my PC's CPU, GPU are slow or is low on memory ..  If you can open 2 video streams in a single window, canvas No.1 for webcam No.1 and canvas No.2 for webcam No.2 and that demo worked for you, just let me test it live or buy a new PC. thanks

Comment: follow up 2  you said: " You can open multiple devices at the same time but mind you that this is going to be taxing for the USB bus."  Ok, I connect first webcam to first usb controller and second webcam to my second usb controller. All I need to know if my PC is or is not too slow to support 2 webcams and if not, to find a right solution. Ok, I can install extra usb controllers. All I need to know is a working 2 webcams demo.  thank you